# Creating IO stream object

Tags: java, properties, io

I ran FindBugs to check my code and it complains that method may fail to close stream:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));
...
```

Is it a mistake or just false positive? Will this stream be properly closed?

Comment: ... and where this stream is being closed? Perhaps when garbage collected only... So FindBugs is right.

Comment: I agree that it is not closed, but its scope is limited enough so should I really care? code looks a lot cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream handling is tedious (prior to Java 7). Before that you have to manually close the stream.

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
   is = new FileInputStream(..);
   // do something with stream
} finally {
   try {
      is.close();
   } catch (Exception ex){ 
      //report problem
   }
}
```

apache commons-lang can shorten the `finally` clause by its `IOUtils.closeQuitely(is)`, but note that it hides the exception

Answer (score 2):

FindBugs is correct, the stream will remain open (at least until the end of the program or it is garbage collected). The stream tyou pass to the the `load()` method is not closed as the API states.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29